# how i can display the file path in imce?

Tags: theming, files

i want display the file location path in the imce : 
i opened the imce-file-list.tpl.php and i found that :

```
<tr id="<?php print $raw = rawurlencode($file['name']); ?>">
    <td class="name"><?php print $raw; ?></td>
    <td class="size" id="<?php print $file['size']; ?>"><?php print format_size($file['size']); ?></td>
    <td class="width"><?php print $file['width']; ?></td>
    <td class="height"><?php print $file['height']; ?></td>
    <td class="date" id="<?php print $file['date']; ?>"><?php print format_date($file['date'], 'short'); ?></td>
  </tr>
```

i want print $file[path] but it not working
[image]